# Message: "Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor has stopped working" on x64 debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging

Since this morning I keep getting this same message "Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor has stopped working" and no matter how many times I restart VS or Windows, that doesn't help. Unfortunately I must use x64 debugging due to third party components. I had no significant changes on the system. From last time everything worked fine.

I've seen this question 
[VS2008: Unable to start debugging, Remote Debugging Monitor has been closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059015/vs2008-unable-to-start-debugging-remote-debugging-monitor-has-been-closed)
and it helped me to understand what is happening but doesn't help me fix the problem...

I am debugging x64 app in local and remote debugger snaps always at the same point of the app start up. The other application still works fine.

Does anyone have some solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar debugger issue where details showed that "Fault Module Name" is SYMSRV.dll. So I've fixed that by ticking off "Microsoft Symbol Servers" (Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols) and cleaning symbols cache.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm not good at English. I had the same problem. It only happened on my workstation win7 VS2010+SP1. I found that it happened when the program trying to load the assembly "EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.Configuration.Design.dll". Strangely, this assembly references itself! so when the program execution is passing through the statement Assembly.Load("EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.Configuration.Design") in debug mode, the msvsmon.exe crashes with this error message: "visual studio remote debugging monitor has stopped working".

Answer (score 0):

Go to “Start > Run”. Type the following path and hit Enter
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64\msvsmon.exe