# visual studio 2015 fatal error on test debug

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Since today, i receive this message:

[image]

After this i receive `visual studio 2015 remote debugger has stopped working`

No matter how many times I restart VS or Windows, that doesn't help. 
I've read this [Message: “Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor has stopped working” on x64 debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363168/message-visual-studio-remote-debugging-monitor-has-stopped-working-on-x64-deb)  and this question 
[vs2008-unable-to-start-debugging-remote-debugging-monitor-has-been-closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059015/vs2008-unable-to-start-debugging-remote-debugging-monitor-has-been-closed)
 but doesn't help me fix the problem...

I am debugging x64 c++ test in local and  debugger stops loading symbols always at the same point: `'vstest.executionengine.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscordacwks.dll'. Symbols loaded.`

What can i do?

Comment: Is your code involved with ComObjects by any chance?

Comment: That is CORDBG_E_TIMEOUT, should be pretty noticeable from the debugger being catatonic for a while.  Environmental problem, something is interfering with the communication with the remote debugger.  Too much crapware tends to be involved with anything you'd do with a network connection, aggressively disabling anti-malware and firewall and whatnot on both ends should be your next step.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem :)

[image]

from this post: [Visual Studio 2015 RTM - Debugging not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31580182/visual-studio-2015-rtm-debugging-not-working)